# how to select the same indexes in two (more) listboxes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, listbox

See, I have two `listboxes: listBox1, listBox2,` both having multiple selection meaning that few items can be selected in each `listbox` separately.

I need to make a method or smth for this:

If you select the items in one `listbox`, items of the same indexes must be automatically selected in another, and vice versa.

I know how to manage that with only one selection.

Please help!

Comment: Show as what you have tried so far...

Comment: Also, winforms, wpf or what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact scenario but you can use this work-around to select the same indexes in both `ListBoxes`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int index;//Your Index select in any listbox
    listBox1.SetSelected(index,true);
    listBox2.SetSelected(index,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have n listboxes:

```
List<ListBox> MyList=new List<ListBox>();

  int index;

Mylist.add(ListBox1);
MyList.add(ListBox2);
....

private void ApplyIndex(int index)
{
   foreach(ListBox li in MyList)
     {
         li.SelectedIndex=index;      
      }
}
```

For every ListBox i add a `selection_change` event to get the index:

```
  private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           int x= listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            ApplyIndex(x);
         }

private void listBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           int x= listBox2.SelectedIndex;
            ApplyIndex(x);
         }

......
```

Answer (score 0):

If Winforms, here's a little class that should do the trick (untested).

```
class SelectionIndexDifference {

    List<int> previousIndices = new List<int>();

    public event Action<int, bool> SelectionChanged;

    public void SetSelectionChange(SelectedIndexCollection selectedIndices) {
        var newIndices = new List<int> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndices.Count; i++) {
            newIndices.Add ((int)selectedIndices [i]);
        }

        var addedIndices = new SortedSet<int> (newIndices);
        addedIndices.ExceptWith (previousIndices);
        var removedIndices = new SortedSet<int> (previousIndices);
        removedIndices.ExceptWith (newIndices);

        foreach (var index in addedIndices) {
            SelectionChanged (index, true);
        }
        foreach (var index in removedIndices) {
            SelectionChanged (index, false);
        }
        previousIndices = newIndices;
    }
}
```

In your form you can create an instance of this class as a field (call it `selectDiff`), and in the constructor (after initialize components), you can sign up the events.

```
partial class FormX {
    SelectionIndexDifference selectDiff = new SelectionIndexDifference ();

    public FormX() {
        InitializeComponent ();

        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
            selectDiff.SetSelectionChange (listBox1.SelectedItems);
        };
        listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
            selectDiff.SetSelectionChange (listbox2.SelectedItems);
        };

        selectDiff.SelectionChanged += listBox1.SetSelected;
        selectDiff.SelectionChanged += listBox2.SetSelected;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

You can probably make this more efficient by removing the need to update the listbox whose selection changed from the user's input - by having multiple instances of `SelectIndexDifference` (one for each listbox), where you don't subscribe the respective listbox to SelectionChanged, for example, if we were keeping 3 listboxes in sync:

```
listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
    selectDiff1.SetSelectionChange (listBox1.SelectedItems);
};
selectDiff1.SelectionChanged += listBox2.SetSelected;
selectDiff1.SelectionChanged += listBox3.SetSelected;


listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
    selectDiff2.SetSelectionChange (listbox2.SelectedItems);
};
selectDiff2.SelectionChanged += listBox1.SetSelected;
selectDiff2.SelectionChanged += listBox3.SetSelected;


listBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
    selectDiff3.SetSelectionChange (listBox1.SelectedItems);
};
selectDiff3.SelectionChanged += listBox1.SetSelected;
selectDiff3.SelectionChanged += listBox2.SetSelected;
```

However, this will consume N times the memory because "previousIndices" is stored for each instance, although they should always really have the same indices. It's possible to improve this to store it once and still have the multiple instances like that for the events. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I get your idea, but the prog gives an error on selectDiff.SetSelectionChange(listBox1.SelectedIndices) "The best overloaded method has some invalid arguments"
Strange, `cause SelectedIndices is of exact type SelectedIndexCollection

Comment: What error? I assume because the argument type of SetSelectionChange needs changing to `ListBox.SelectedIndexCollection` (It's a nested class of the ListBox). You could probably get away with using an `IList` too.